# explanation for why is the following set not compact

Tags: general-topology

The set A$= (0,1] \subset{R}$ equipped with the usual topology, is not a compact set because it's not closed and bounded. Going by the choice of covers, we can choose an open set U $= (\frac{1}{i},2)$ and say that we can not choose finite sub-covers of the type-U such that A $\subset \bigcup_i^n U_i.$ I understand this part well, but couldn't we choose two open sets such as B$= (-1,2)$ and C$= (-2, 2)$ and say that A $\subset (B \cup C)$ and hence I have two sub-covers(finite) which cover the original set A and hence A is compact? 
Where is my argument's flaw?

Comment: The flaw is that *one* open cover having a finite subcover is not the same thing as *all* open covers having finite subcovers.  Showing that *one* cover has a finite subcover does not show something is compact. But showing that one open cover does *not* have a finite subcover is enough to show it isn't compact.

Comment: @LiChunMin Did you *read* the post?

Comment: My fault. Sorry about that.

Comment: @fleablood: Thank you for the additional info about proving the "un-compactness". I understand the flaw now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove something is compact, you have to prove that **any** open cover has a finite subcover.

You have just shown a particular cover that has a finite subcover, which does not prove that it is compact.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an analogy:

Definition: A *prime* number is a positive integer greater than 1 whose *only* positive whole factors are itself and one.

Counter Example:  15 is not prime because it has factors 3 and 5.

Confused student:  But what if we chose factors 1 and 15.  Those would be factors that are only itself and one.  So it should be prime.

... Now lets do the same with compact...

Definition:  A *compact* set is a set whose *only* open covers will have finite subcovers.

Counter example:  $(0, 1]$ as it has open cover $\{(1/i, 2)\}$ that has no finite subcover.

Confused student:  But what if we chose the open cover $\{(0,2)\}$.  It is finite cover.  Why isn't it compact?

.....

Notice:  *Every* set, open, closed, bounded, unbounded, compact, not compact, *EVERY* set has a finite open subcover.  Just take $\mathcal U = X$ where $X$ is the entire space.  That *is* an open cover.  And it's as finite as it gets.